# Umbraco Can't add media :

Tags: umbraco7

Actual Error: Value "png" of type "System.String" could not be converted to type "System.Int32" whcih is expected by property type "umbracoExtension"

Been working on a new site for a week and I find I cannot upload any media at all.

Umbraco version 7.5.3

I did have a bunch of orphaned nodes which I have manually removed, but I think that was just another problem.

If I change the connection string and point to a different DB the Media Upload works fine.

Stumped. Any Ideas

[Umbraco Media Upload Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAtQK.png)

Answer (score 1):

I think you did the same as me: accidentally changed the data type "Label's" (aka NoEdit) Value Type to Integer. It was set to String originally. It is an internal data type, many internal property like umbracoExtension for Image property group use this data type.

Try to go to the Backoffice/Developer/Data Types, select "Label" data type and check if the Value Type is not set to Integer. If yes, change it back to String.